# Instalador multiidioma de aplicación Java en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi instalador de netbeans sea multiidioma? Uso el que viene con Netbeans en botón derecho sobre el proyecto > Package As y lo genera perfectamente, pero no se cómo customizarlo ni hacerlo multiidioma como me han pedido.

Answer (score 1):

Buenos dias,

Para crear una aplicación multiidioma en java, lo que tendrás que crear será una clase idioma, que extenderá de la clase Properties.

```
public class Idioma extends Properties{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Idioma(String idioma){

    //Modificar si quieres añadir mas idiomas
    //Cambia el nombre de los ficheros o añade los necesarios
    switch(idioma){
        case "Español":
                getProperties("espanol.properties");
                break;
        case "Inglés":
                getProperties("ingles.properties");
                break;
        default:
                getProperties("espanol.properties");
    }

}

private void getProperties(String idioma) {
    try {
        this.load( getClass().getResourceAsStream(idioma) );
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
}
```

Incluima la clase idioma que acabamos de crear a nuestro proyecto.
Ahora vamos a crear un fichero de propiedades. Para ello clic derecho sobre nuestro proyecto **New -> Other** y llegaremos a esta pantalla:

- Filtramos por prop, y enseguida nos salta el tipo de fichero Properties File.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le damos a next y lo guardamos con el nombre del idioma que queremos implementar en nuestro proyecto.

Crearemos un fichero properties por cada idioma que queramos mostrar. Bien una vez abierto el fichero, usaremos el siguiente formato por cada elemento que queramos traducir:

**nombre_texto = valor**

## Creación de ficheros properties

### ESPAÑOL

Por ejemplo en el fichero espanol.properties:

```
saludo=Hola
titulo=Ejemplo
cambio=Cambia idioma
espanol=Español
ingles=Ingles
frances=Frances
```

### FRANCES

En otro fichero serie el frances y lo llamamos frances.properties:

```
saludo=Bonjour
titulo=Exemple
cambio=Change une langue
espanol=Espagnol
ingles=Anglais
frances=Français
```

### INGLÉS

```
saludo=Hello
titulo=Example
cambio=Change language
espanol=Spanish
ingles=English
frances=French
```

## Creación de la clase main

```
package ejemplo_multiidioma;

public class frmPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public frmPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    
    cambiarIdioma("Espanol");
}

public void cambiarIdioma(String nombreIdioma){
    
    idioma=new Idioma(nombreIdioma);
    
    btnCambio.setText(idioma.getProperty("cambio"));
    this.setTitle(idioma.getProperty("titulo"));
    lblHola.setText(idioma.getProperty("saludo"));
    
    cmbIdiomas.removeAllItems();
    
    String idiomas[]={
                      idioma.getProperty("espanol"),
                      idioma.getProperty("ingles"),
                      idioma.getProperty("frances")
                      };
    
    for(int i=0;i<idiomas.length;i++){
        cmbIdiomas.addItem(idiomas[i]);
    }
    
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnCambio = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblHola = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cmbIdiomas = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btnCambio.setText("jButton1");
    btnCambio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCambioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblHola.setText("jLabel1");

    cmbIdiomas.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Español", "Ingles", "Frances" }));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(145, 145, 145)
            .addComponent(btnCambio)
            .addContainerGap(120, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(lblHola, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(cmbIdiomas, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(75, 75, 75))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(lblHola, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addComponent(cmbIdiomas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(btnCambio)
            .addContainerGap(67, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCambioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    switch(cmbIdiomas.getSelectedIndex()){

        case 0:
            cambiarIdioma("Español");
            break;
        case 1:
            cambiarIdioma("Ingles");
            break;
        case 2:
            cambiarIdioma("Frances");
            break;

    }
    
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new frmPrincipal().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnCambio;
private javax.swing.JComboBox cmbIdiomas;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblHola;
// End of variables declaration                   
private Idioma idioma;
}
```

La estructura de paquetes quedaría de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora que ya lo tenemos todo ejecutamos...

## ESPAÑOL

Tenemos el programa en español

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## INGLÉS

Ahora si seleccionamos en el comboBox inglés y a continuación clicamos en el botón, cambia todo el programa totalmente a Inglés.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## FRANCÉS

Y por último si le seleccionamos francés se nos cambia todo el programa a francés.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Un saludo.